# iRODS configuration - Could not start iRODS server during

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I've installed postgres as database and then iRODS in Ubuntu 14.04. Then I start its configuration

`sudo /var/lib/irods/packaging/setup_irods.sh`

After the configuration phase, when iRODS starts the updtating, the first 4 steps go well

```
Stopping iRODS server...

-----------------------------
Running irods_setup.pl...

Step 1 of 4:  Configuring database user...
    Updating user's .pgpass...
        Skipped.  File already uptodate.

Step 2 of 4:  Creating database and tables...
    Checking whether iCAT database exists...
        [mydb] on [localhost] found.
    Updating user's .odbc.ini...
    Creating iCAT tables...
        Skipped.  Tables already created.
    Testing database communications...

Step 3 of 4:  Configuring iRODS server...
    Updating /etc/irods/server_config.json...
    Updating /etc/irods/database_config.json...

Step 4 of 4:  Configuring iRODS user and starting server...
    Updating iRODS user's ~/.irods/irods_environment.json...
    Starting iRODS server...
```

but at the end I get this error

```
Could not start iRODS server.
    Starting iRODS server...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/irods/iRODS/scripts/python/get_db_schema_version.py", line 77, in <module>
    current_schema_version = get_current_schema_version(cfg)
  File "/var/lib/irods/iRODS/scripts/python/get_db_schema_version.py", line 61, in get_current_schema_version
    'get_current_schema_version: failed to find result line for schema_version\n\n{}'.format(format_cmd_result(result)))
RuntimeError: get_current_schema_version: failed to find result line for schema_version


return code: [0]
stdout:

stderr:
ERROR:  relation "r_grid_configuration" does not exist
LINE 1: ...option_value                                 from R_GRID_CON...
                                                             ^

Confirming catalog_schema_version... Success
Validating [/var/lib/irods/.irods/irods_environment.json]... Success
Validating [/etc/irods/server_config.json]... Success
Validating [/etc/irods/hosts_config.json]... Success
Validating [/etc/irods/host_access_control_config.json]... Success
Validating [/etc/irods/database_config.json]... Success
(1) Waiting for process bound to port 5432 ... [-]
(2) Waiting for process bound to port 5432 ... [-]
(4) Waiting for process bound to port 5432 ... [-]
Port 5432 In Use ... Not Starting iRODS Server


Install problem:
    Cannot start iRODS server.
Found 0 processes:
        There are no iRODS servers running.

Abort.
```

Have you any ideas on what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I don't have enough reputation to comment:

Which version of iRODS are you using?

### This portion of the output:

```
    Creating iCAT tables...
        Skipped.  Tables already created.
```

combined with this portion:

```
ERROR:  relation "r_grid_configuration" does not exist
```

suggests that the setup ran before, but only partially completed, leaving the system in a broken state. I would recommend reinstallating from scratch, which includes:

1. Uninstalling the iRODS icat and db plugin packages:

   - `sudo dpkg -P irods-icat irods-database-plugin-postgres`
   - note: make sure to use the `-P`, so that the configuration files are removed from dpkg's database.
2. Dropping and remaking the database
3. Deleting the following directories:

   - `sudo rm -rf /tmp/irods /etc/irods /var/lib/irods`
4. Reinstalling the packages and running `sudo /var/lib/irods/packaging/setup_irods.sh`

### This portion of the output:

```
(1) Waiting for process bound to port 5432 ... [-]
(2) Waiting for process bound to port 5432 ... [-]
(4) Waiting for process bound to port 5432 ... [-]
Port 5432 In Use ... Not Starting iRODS Server
```

suggests that you are using port 5432 as your iRODS server port. This will conflict with the default Postgres port. I recommend using the default iRODS server port of `1247`. This value was queried during setup as:

```
iRODS server's port [1247]:
```

and is recorded in `/etc/irods/server_config.json` under the `zone_port` entry.

### iRODS-Chat:

It may be easier to continue this on the [iRODS-Chat google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/irod-chat). Repairing installs can require back-and-forth communication, which may not be inline with standard stackoverflow usage.